# Why doesn't Hogwarts teach music?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

> “Ah, music," he said, wiping his eyes. "A magic beyond all we do here!” - Albus Dumbledore, *Harry Potter and The Philospher's Stone*

So, Dumbledore is pretty darned fond of music.

We also know that, under Dumbledore, Hogwarts has been barely regulated (it's mentioned later on that Dumbledore basically has free reign to teach what he likes and hire what teachers he likes).

There's also a fair amount of extracurricular activities (quidditch, gobstones, chess etc.). These kids get up to some things.

We know that there are some popular and successful musicians in the magical world (Celestina Warbeck and The Weird Sisters are among them). Back out in the real world young people are very likely to use their teenage years trying to emulate popular musicians.

There also seems to be (on the whole) very little poverty among Hogwarts students. The Weasleys are always a little short, but just about everyone else can afford a heap of books each year, uniform, wand, broom and a pet with no trouble. So it wouldn't be too ridiculous to get an instrument tutor in for kids who wanted to play.

And yet, Hogwarts has:

- No instrument tutors
- No students who play an instrument in their own time.
- No band/choir/orchestra (Remember, the movies are not canon).
- Nobody even seems to listen to music. (There are magical radios, but we only see them outside of Hogwarts)

So why not? The headmaster loves it, the kids love some musical acts (even though they don't seem to listen to them), but no kids care?

Comment: Of course the HP movies are canon. They're adaptations of the books, but canon nonetheless.

Comment: I don't remember properly, but one of the movies had the students singing something like a carrol and Flitwick conducting them with his wand.

Comment: There is a school song sung at the first start-of-term feast, which is vividly described in the book as a terrible din (lots of different tunes going on at once). The film (which is not canon) makes this a choir of children, conducted by Flitwick, holding massive toads which are also singing. This is completely unlike the books and is not canon.

Comment: @Roberto - Many would say that by virtue of it being a adaptation it cannot be canon. In any event the bond and movies are very clearly not set in the same continuity, so it makes sense to limit an answer to just one of them.

Comment: We don't have AFAIK any evidence to prove or disprove the teaching of magic at Hogwarts

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Except for the quote I started the ticket with. Dumbledore describes music as "magic beyond all we do here". Which would make no logical sense if music was among the things done at Hogwarts.

Comment: According to Dumbledore love is the greatest magic of all, yet Hogwarts doesn’t seem to teach much of that either.

Comment: There is music at Hogwarts, at least. They have a school anthem (Hoggy Warty Hogwarts). It is probably one of the *many* courses we never see in the books or films. I can't believe they never bothered to show an Arithmancy session! Dumbledore's line about 'beyond all we do here' may just mean there's no *magical* music being studied... just mundane music.

Comment: @TylerH we do spend quite a lot of time reading about the tricky decision of which courses to take in OWLs and then NEWTs. The courses are discussed in some detail. Music is not mentioned. - while we never see an Arithmancy lesson, we do see Hermione poring over textbooks and Harry does visit the classroom. I’m not sure there’s much basis for a lot of unmentioned subjects. Not least, there’s one teacher for each subject and they all sit together at meals.

Comment: How do we know there aren't other kids there that are "just getting by" like the weasleys? We're never shown the world from anybody else's perspective, and from Harry's perspective Ron is the only one that matters

Comment: That might work, except for the fact the Weasleys are treated differently because of their relative poverty. They’re singled out for wearing hand-me-downs, and occasionally bullied for it. Sure, having a lot of children doesn’t help, but they do seem fairly exceptional.

Answer (score 5):

[Music](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Music) and [Muggle Music](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Muggle_Music) are both taught at Hogwarts as an extra-curricular activity, as seen in Gameboy Colour Game '*[*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Chamber_of_Secrets_(GBC))*'.

According to the blurb, Muggle Music classes are only available to third years and above. You can see the classroom below and [here](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/5/50/Music_Classroom.png). It features drums, a piano and choral stands.

[image]

Comment: OP specified in their question that they were asking exclusively about the books.

Comment: @ibid - Did they? I must have missed that.. They certainly stated that they didn't consider the *movies* to be canon, but there's nothing about the games

Comment: Typically games are ranked below movies in "canonical precedence" lists... as I'm sure you know. Seems to reason if OP doesn't consider movies canon (however silly that position is), they also don't consider games canon, either.

Comment: I’m starting to consider the games Canon.